# How to remove [" and "] from string using Regex in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

My string is

["Passwords must have at least one non letter or digit character. Passwords must have at least one lowercase ('a'-'z')."]

and I just need to remove the **first** `["` and the **last** `"]`

Comment: 1) Are they always the first and last characters? 2) what is the current attempt, and how does it not function correctly?

Comment: `JSON.parse(str)[0]`

Comment: Yes. I tried with `errors.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, "")` but it removes other special char as well inside the string

Comment: Anyway, perhaps something like: `str = str.replace(/^\["/, "").replace(/"]$/, "")` .. ymmv depending on other 'undisclosed details'.

Comment: lol, your are welcome - just assumed it was json :P

Comment: Use `s.replace(/^\["([^]*)"]$/, "$1")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with [String.prototype.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) specifying the *`beginIndex`* (from) and *`startIndex`* (up to) where the *extraction* will be taken place:

> The [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) method extracts a section of a string and returns it as a new string, without modifying the original string.

```js
var str = `["Passwords must have at least one non letter or digit character. Passwords must have at least one lowercase ('a'-'z')."]`;
str = str.slice(2, -2);
console.log(str);
```

Comment: you mean `2, -2` of course